# Set up removable media as automatic decrypt key

Tags: encryption

I have a ton of floppy disks and was thinking I might be able to put them to use. My computer has a floppy drive and I was thinking I could set up different floppy drives as different automatic "keys" to decrypt different files within my home partition. Would it be possible to set up my system such that I insert a floppy disk, the computer reads a file with a private key on it, and then uses that key to attempt and decrypt a set of files?

Comment: I don't think floppy drives can tell the system when a disk has been inserted (or removed). But using a keyfile should work on any removable media, so it should work? If you manually run the "decrypt" script after the disk's ready, so not fully automatic.